# White spaces are lost when echoing under php

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I've got the following issue with PHP and PostgreSQL.
In a table I added the following value, mark the spaces.

```
Things: 10                     POLI
```

When I read this out with PHP it will become

```
Things 10 POLI
```

My simpified code (for an ideal world without errors) is:

```
$query = "SELECT stuff, thing, planets FROM 42 WHERE answer = '-'";
$result = pg_query($connection, $query);
$resultTable = pg_fetch_all($result);
```

Then with

```
echo "Things: $result[stuff]";
```

My question is, which step eliminates all the white spaces? And how to get these spaces back? I know that most people want to remove them, I want to keep them.

Comment: Is it going to HTML?  'Cause all browsers will scrunch multiple spaces down to a single space, unless you wrap your string in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: It's even better instead of `echoing` traced variables just watch them in process with [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/). You won't believe how tremendously it simplifies the bugfixing. )

Comment: XDebug comes with an Eclipse plugin. Nice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is not a PHP issue, but a HTML issue, becauyse if you output with echo, you do in fact generate HTML code.

The HTML specification defines, that multiple consecutive spaces get rendered as only one space.

If you want to avoid this, wrap a `<pre>` tag around the string:

```
echo "<pre>Things: $result[stuff]</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because browser does not recognize more than one space, you can use this code to convert consective spaces to `&nbsp;` (space understood by browser)

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $origText);
```

Or alternatively wrap your text in `<pre>` tag if that suites your requirements as suggested in comments below.

Comment: ... or just wrap your output in '<pre>' element, I usually prefer that way. )

Comment: And I wouldn't say 'does not recognise'. ) It simply ignores the repeated whitespace when rendering most of the elements.